# Who cursed Narada that he would tell the truth but no one would believe him?

Tags: narada

The wiki page on [Narada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narada) has this line

> Once his knowledge became a hindrance in God's designs. He was
> therefore cursed that although he would tell the truth and warn
> people, they would never believe him.

There is no attribution to the line nor is anything expounded in the wiki article. Does anyone who cursed Narada such ? And under what circumstance ?

Comment: you could add a citation needed in that wikipedia article.

Comment: The closest curse I can think of is the *Daksha's* curse, however, it didn't involve any - *"he would tell the truth and warn people, they would never believe him."*

Comment: @Vivikta: Yup, that's what I thought of, but that curse is just that you will roam like a nomad, nothing about people not believing him...